# Why do my rigid bodies randomly activate?

Tags: animation

I just wanted to make a little rigid body simulation where a house explodes. But everything activates before it is ready. I have no idea why this could be happening. I am pretty bad with Blender so it might be something on my part.
[image][image]

Comment: please provide blend file so we can check it out

Comment: i can't it won't let my put a file

Comment: Use the https://blend-exchange.com/ link to upload a file and then past the link into you Question that you can edit.  I usually have to Save As and reduce the file to what needs to be worked on, as https://blend-exchange.com/ has a size limit.

Answer (score 0):

Animate WHEN you want the Active object to start its dynamics simulation.

1. select frame 1
2. In the active element disable Dynamic, and click the white dot next to it (hover over it for the help text)
   [image]
3. The white dot changes to a white triangle
4. Set the Playback frame to the point you want the Dynamic simulation
   to start (frame where Sphere hits the house)
5. In the House Active RB, check the box next to Dynamic and again
   click on the Animate Property triangle to its right.

[image]

Run your Playback -- that should do it.

You might also want to consider using the Object -> Quick Effects -> Quick Explode in the future, where you'd have the front glass window and parts of the house roof each as an object separate from the house, with sub-object faces that would explode.